# Android: ExoPlayer - Audio stream playing in one app stops when exoplayer instance is initialised in another app

Tags: android, audio-streaming, exoplayer, shared-resource

There are two apps using Exoplayer. AppA and AppB

- AppA starts streaming audio.
- AppB is then launched which initialises the exoplayer instance. NOTE: No stream is yet played on AppB.
- But right away AppA stops playing the audio.

Could someone help understand this behaviour with the new initialisation of the exoplayer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that we were requesting for audio focus after initialisation instead of when the user requested a play event. 
Basic mistake I suppose.

No issue in terms of the ExoPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably ExoPlayer gets garbage collected. You should use [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground), to make sure a service stays alive as much as possible without being killed by the system.